# My page is not scrollable for some reason

Tags: html, css

For some reason, I can only view all the content when I zoom out the page. When I view at 100%, I can only the parts of the page. I think I accidentally changed the border somewhere because it was working fine at one point. Not sure whether it's the black border which is around the whole page that's making the page not scrollable.

```
.border {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border: 13px solid #000;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo{
display: block;
text-align: center;

margin-top: 4em;
margin-bottom: 2em;
} 

.intro{
font-family: 'PRIND';
font-style: normal;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 20;
line-height: 0.4em;

text-align: center;

margin-top: 7em;
margin-bottom: 20em;
}

.box-1-container{
width:82%;
margin:auto;
}

.box-1{
background-color: #D6EAF8;

padding-top: 4%;

}

.about-me-text{

font-family: 'SansationBold';
font-size: 30px;

border-top: 7px solid rgb(217, 217, 217);


margin-left: 3%;
margin-right: 70%;

}

.about-me-text h1{
margin: 0;
}

#oscar{

font-size: 37px;

margin-bottom: 100%;

}

.para1{
font-family: 'SansationBold';

text-align:left;

margin-left: 3%;
margin-right: 48%;

line-height: 1.6em;

border-right: thick solid #E5E7E9  ;
}
```

Comment: Present a minimal executable example if you want help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need to see your HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your css code add this:

```
html{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: It changed nothing